# OutOfMemoryError when use ResultSet to query from Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, memory, resultset

My query returns with 31,000 results with 12 columns for each row, and each row contains roughly 8,000 characters (8KB per row). Here is how I processed:

```
public List<MyTableObj> getRecords(Connection con) {
    List<MyTableObj> list = new ArrayList<MyTableObj>();
    String sql = "my query..."; 

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;

    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    st.setFetchSize(50);
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    try {
        System.out.println("Before MemoryFreeSize = " + (double)Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");

        while ( rs.next() ) {
            MyTableObjitem item = new MyTableObj();
            item.setColumn1( rs.getString("column1") );
            ... ...
            item.setColumn12( rs.getString("column12") );

            list.add( item );
        } // end loop

        // try to release some memory, but it's not working at all
        if ( st != null ) st.close();
        if ( rs != null ) rs.close();
        st = null; rs = null;
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) { //do something }
    System.out.println("After MemoryFreeSize = " + (double)Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");

    return list;
} // end getRecords
```

If each row takes 8kb memory, 31k should take 242mb memory. After finish looping the query result, my remaining memory is only 142mb, which is not enough to finish rest of my other process.

I searched many solutions and I tried to set my heap memory to 512mb `-Xmx512m -Xms512m`, and I also set the fetch size `setFetchSize(50)`.

I suspect it's the ResultSet occupied too much memories, the results may stored in the client-side catch. However, after I clear up some object ( `st.close()` and `rs.close()` ), even I manually called the garbage collector `System.gc()`, the free memory after the loop never increase (why?).

Let's just assume I can not change the database design, and I need all query results. How can I free more memory after processing?

P.S.: I also tried to not using the `ResultSet.getString()` and relace it with hardcode String, and after looping, I got 450mb free memory.

I found that, if I do:

```
// + counter to make the value different for each row, for testing purpose
item.setColumn1( "Constant String from Column1" + counter );
... ...
item.setColumn12( "Constant String from Column12" + counter );
counter++;
```

It used only around 60MB memory.
But if I do:

```
item.setColumn1( rs.getString("column1") );
... ...
item.setColumn12( rs.getString("column12") );
```

It used up to 380MB memory.

I already did `rs.close();` and `rs = null;` `//rs is Result instance`, but this seems does not help. Why there is so much memory usage different between these 2 approaches? In both approaches I only passed in String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think many people may encounter this issue, but I still feel like to post my solution for reference.

***Before in my code,***
The query is:

```
String sql = "SELECT column1, column2 ... FROM mytable";
```

and the setter for MyTableObj is:

```
public void setColumn1(String columnStr) {
    this._columnStr = columnStr == null ? "" : columnStr.trim();
}
```

***After update:***

What I updated is just use the trim in query instead of using java code:

```
String sql = "SELECT TRIM(column1), TRIM(column2) ... FROM mytable";

public void setColumn1(String columnStr) {
    this._columnStr = columnStr == null ? "" : columnStr;
}
```

Using this udpated code, it takes only roughly ***100 MB*** memory, which is a lot less than previous memory usage (***380 MB***).

<strike>I still can not give a valid reason why java trim consume more memory the sql trim, if anyone knows the reason, please help me to explain it. I will appreciate it a lot.</strike>

After many test, I found that it's data. Each row takes 8 KB and 31,000 rows takes about 240MB memory. `TRIM` in the query can only works for those short data.

Since data is large and memory is limit, I can only limit my query result for now.

Comment: Actually you're probably just observing it wrong. You think it's using "too much" memory, but it's just using what's available and hasn't garbage collected the garbage. You don't mention OutOfMemoryError, so I'm assuming that you're trusting the Runtime.freeMemory() values and just **thinking** that you're running out of memory.

Comment: Actually most memory is not consumed by String.trim(), this is the part I observe wrong. It should be the data itself. If each data is 8 KB, then 30,000 data have to use up to 240 MB memory.

Comment: For correct results a profiler should be used. Not Runtime.freeMemory().

Answer (score 0):

You should narrow down your queries, try to get more specific and if necessary add limit in your queries your java can't handle too large results

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the data you're getting in memory at the same time (so you can't process it in chunks), then you'll need to have enough memory for it. Try it with 1G of memory.

Forget calling System.gc(), that's not going to help (it will be called before an OutOfMemoryException is thrown anyway).

I also noticed you're not closing the connection. You should probably do that as well (if you don't have a connection pool yet, set one up).

And of course you can use a profiler to see where the memory is actually going to. What you're doing now is pure guesswork.

Comment: The connection is actually closed after using the `getRecords(Connection con)` function.